# debug Lexmark 08zero driver in Linux

Tags: linux, debug, cups, lexmark-printer

Fedora 3: trying to make Lexmark Z24020 print (btw, I could not install driver on xubuntu >11 either because it is on a 64bit machine and the Lexmark driver is for 32bit only). It did work on same FC3 installation, when I compiled all sorts of updates and mangled the original FC3 system. Now I restored FC3 to its original state and printing aborts when sent to the installed Lexmark printer (HP LaserJet P1102w works already). Cups error log indicates that printdriver component of the Lexmark software is started, next cups socket is started, but then printdriver stops in error and cups aborts. ldd printdriver is all satisfied. This is with cups 1.1.22.0. Previously, with my mangled FC3 cups was 1.4.6. So the question is: how do I go about debugging, finding out what is incompatible now? Wrote a simple script to start printdriver with ltrace, but this only works if I execute printdriver (which starts the renamed original printdriver) from shell, but ltrace is not working if my printdriver script is called from the cups process. Enough said, and thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser. This is a wall of text and hard to read. If you want more people to read and give you help, please rewrite your question using proper sentences, spacing and capitalisation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of making Lexmark print is solved by compiling cups 1.2 (which is indicated in the Lexmark packaged ppd file as the version of cups) and compiling qgostscript 9.02. Apparently the Lexmark printdriver does not work with earlier versions of cups and ghostscript. This was a brute force, trial-and error, hunch based solution. The question still remains, how to do a debug in this case, how to find the point where the process breaks down.